# BranchOperator is getting skipped airflow

Tags: python, airflow

I have this flow:-

```
execution_date_hour = "{{ execution_date.strftime('%H') }}"

default_args = {
    'owner': 'hourly-airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'catch_up': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
    'email': failure_email_list,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5)
}

dag = DAG('hourly_pipeline_dag',
          default_args=default_args,
          tags=['hourly'],
          schedule_interval='@hourly',
          catchup=False)

taskA = PostgresOperator(dag=dag,
                         task_id='taskA', 
                         postgres_conn_id='database_connection',
                         sql='sql/hourly_entry.sql')

taskb = DummyOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="taskb"
)

taske = DummyOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="taske"
)

taskc = DummyOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="taskc"
)

taskd = DummyOperator(
    dag=dag,
    task_id="taskd"
)

branch_op = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id='branch_op',
    python_callable=lambda
        **kwargs: 'feed_sensor_a' if execution_date_hour == '5' else 'feed_sensor_b',
    dag=dag)

feed_sensor_a = SqlSensor(dag=dag,
                          task_id='feed_sensor_a',
                          conn_id='database_connection',
                          sql='sql/sensor_hourly.sql',
                          poke_interval=30,
                          trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
                          timeout=3600)

feed_sensor_b = SqlSensor(dag=dag,
                          task_id='feed_sensor_b',
                          conn_id='database_connection',
                          sql='sql/sensor.sql',
                          poke_interval=30,
                          trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ONE_SUCCESS,
                          timeout=3600)

taskA >> [taskb,taskc]
taskb >> taskd
taskc >> taske
[taskd,taske] >> branch_op
branch_op >> [feed_sensor_a,feed_sensor_b]
```

Pipeline runs till taskd and taske, branch_op is skipped. Please help, I am stuck on this for soo long. Till taske and taskd it runs fine, branch_op is highlighted in red i.e skipped, don't know what happens here. (All these tasks are dummy tasks, in actual they are HttpOperator and Postgres op).
Thanks in advance, let me know if any other info is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot reproduce failure in task `branch_op`.
However, even if it was running , it was always going to `else` condition because `BranchPythonOperator` does not have `execution_date` in template field list automatically. So I did two things,

- Reformatted DAG a bit
- Updated condition to check for `05` because `%H` transates to this format
- Used argument `op_kwargs` of `BranchPythonOperator` to pass hour.

```
from airflow.models import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

execution_date_hour = "{{ execution_date.strftime('%H') }}"
failure_email_list = ['myemail']

default_args = {
    'owner': 'hourly-airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'catch_up': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 12, 14, 0, 0),
    'email': failure_email_list,
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
}

dag = DAG('hourly_pipeline_dag',
          default_args=default_args,
          tags=['hourly'],
          schedule_interval='@hourly',
          catchup=False)

with dag:
    taskA = DummyOperator(task_id='taskA')
    taskB = DummyOperator(task_id='taskB')
    taskC = DummyOperator(task_id='taskC')
    taskD = DummyOperator(task_id='taskD')
    taskE = DummyOperator(task_id='taskE')

    branch_op = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id= f'branch_op',
        python_callable=lambda hour: 'feed_sensor_5' if hour == "05" else 'feed_sensor_not5',
        op_kwargs={'hour': execution_date_hour},
    )
    feed_sensor_5 = DummyOperator(task_id='feed_sensor_5')
    feed_sensor_not5 = DummyOperator(task_id='feed_sensor_not5')

    taskA >> [taskB,taskC]
    taskB >> taskD
    taskC >> taskE
    [taskD,taskE] >> branch_op
    branch_op >> [feed_sensor_5,feed_sensor_not5]
```

Now it goes to if for execution `2021-05-01 05:00:00` and to else for `2021-05-01 06:00:00`

Comment: Thanks it worked for me. Can you help me with one more doubt, for eg execution date is 2021-06-03 08:00:00 for the dag run, but as the dag run is executing the execution date changes, then when I will again access it, it will return the same execution date as 08 or 09.

Comment: I am accessing execution date as {{ execution_date }} macro

Answer (score 1):

Running your code I don't see the `branch_op` task failing or being skipped.  However, I don't think your `BranchPythonOperator` task will work as you'd like it to.  There are no inputs being passed into the lambda function and `python_callable` is not a templated field for the operator (i.e. the logic is evaluating to the literal string `"{{ execution_date.strftime('%H') }}"` so the flow would always follow `feed_sensor_b`.  Try this instead:

```py
branch_op = BranchPythonOperator(
    task_id="branch_op",
    python_callable=lambda execution_date_hour: "feed_sensor_a" if execution_date_hour == "5" else "feed_sensor_b",
    op_args=[execution_date_hour],
    dag=dag,
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your time it worked. Can you help me with one more doubt, for eg execution date is 2021-06-03 08:00:00 for the dag run, but as the dag run is executing the execution date changes, then when I will again access it, it will return the same execution date as 08 or 09.

Comment: I am accessing execution date as {{ execution_date }} macro

Comment: @ArpitPruthi The `execution_date` in Airflow is not the actual run date/time, but rather the start timestamp of its schedule period.  Meaning the `execution_date` for the same DAG run should not change if it is rerun nor will it change as the DAG is executing.  A completely new DAG run instance will change the `execution_date` since it would yield a different schedule period.  Do you need a more dynamic timestamp for your logic such that the timestamp changes to real wall-clock time?

Comment: Thanks Josh got your point... Can you help me with {{ execution_date.subtract(hours = 5) }}, here instead of hardcoding 5 I want to pass it as a variable, I am not able to find a way to pass a variable and finally use the value of the variable.

Comment: @ArpitPruthi Were you thinking about passing this value as an Airflow Variable, as an output from some function, or some other manner?